# vs code multiple open projects: pydev debugger: unable to find translation

Tags: visual-studio-code, debugpy

I setup a while ago debugging for a small python program, which I developed using docker.
So I used `Python: Remote Attach`, as shown in the official documentation. This worked for me.

Later I started having one workspace for my multiple other project I developed.
However now `debugpy` gets confused and gives me the following error message:

> pydev debugger: unable to find translation for: "/path/to/other/php-project/random-file.php" in ["/path/to/the/to/be/debugged/my-python-project", "/path/to/the/to/be/debugged/my-python-project"] (please revise your path mappings).

I really don't understand, why it picks this random php file from the other project.

As I mentioned I use the configuration from vs code official documentation.

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Remote Attach",
            "type": "debugpy",
            "request": "attach",
            "connect": {
                "host": "localhost",
                "port": 5678
            },
            "pathMappings": [
                {
                    "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
                    "remoteRoot": "."
                }

            ],
            "justMyCode": true
        }
    ]
}
```

I already tried changing local root in the path mapping: `"localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/my-python-project"`. This did not change anything.

When I open the project only as folder without the workspace, debugging works as before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had an debugpoint enabled on the file from the other php project.
After closing it, everything worked as before.